# Referencing stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra

I'm new to Sinatra and am trying to reference a stylesheet from an ERB file. I have tried the methods used in "[Loading Stylesheets in Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340335/loading-stylesheets-in-sinatra)" but the stylesheet is still not loading.

My HTML is in views/index.rb and the stylesheet is views/styles/main.css. The controller logic is in app.rb.

The HTML itself is displaying when I load it on a local server.

The folder structure is:

```
|-- app.rb
|-- config.ru
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- lib
|-- spec
|   |-- spec_helper.rb
|-- views
|   |-- index.erb
|   |-- styles
|   |   |-- main.css
```

app.rb is:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

index.erb did not work:

```
<link href="<%= url('views/styles/main.css') %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%= url('/main.css') %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

My repo is: https://github.com/natstar93/Thermostat-day3

Can someone help me work out how to reference the stylesheet?

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/natstar93/Thermostat-Api ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I will update that in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Static assets like stylesheets should go in a `public` directory](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Static%20Files), not `views` which is for templates that produce different output for each request.

You should create a directory named `public` alongside `views` and copy the `styles` directory to it. Then the url to the stylesheet will be `/styles/main.css`:

```
 <link href="<%= url('/styles/main.css') %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You might also need to enable static asset serving (the docs suggest that it is disabled by default in modular apps, but actually it appears to depend on whether the `public` dir exists – it can’t hurt to be explicit). Add this to your app class to turn this on:

```
enable :static
```